# Adaptive Cards: Visibility of element depending on value of a ChoiceSet

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am trying to show TextBlock elements on my adaptive card depending in the value selected in a `ChoiceSet` (radio buttons). And I am not getting it to work properly.

The `ChoiceSet` does not have an `ActionSet` integrated, so I cannot call a `ToggleVisibility` action on selection. Then I tried to use the `selectAction` Property, but neither the `Input.ChoiceSet` nor `Input.Choice` support this property. 
The last approach was to use the `"$when"` property on the element I want to toggle and bind it to the value of the `ChoiceSet`. Depending on which value it has, the element should be shown or hidden. But I do not get it to work, I tried
`"$when": "{damagepart=2}"` but it seems that only works with some kind of data binding?!

I am not able to find a proper example of that in the decumentation or in the samples of adaptivecards.io...

Does anyone have an example or some hints on how to get this task solved?

Comment: Is this card in a bot or what?

Comment: Yes, this card will be sent by a bot

Comment: To what channel?

Comment: webchat / emulator

Comment: This won't be possible in Emulator, and it will be very difficult in Web Chat. You will need to [extend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/extensibility) Web Chat's Adaptive Card renderer with custom code. Can you post your Web Chat client code so that I can base my answer on what you have in terms of whether you're using Node or the CDN and if you're using React?

Comment: Nope, stopped on this one. Found out its on the roadmap in "future": https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/25-client-side-update-card-upon-input-changes-or-button-presses

Comment: Suit yourself. Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

While this can theoretically be done in Web Chat using the extensibility features of Adaptive Cards, you may also not that this feature is in the Adaptive Cards roadmap: https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/25-client-side-update-card-upon-input-changes-or-button-presses

Answer (score 0):

I made this example that might be useful for you.

The column section that contain a text box and a action hyperlink will hide and show depending on the condition or the value of the variable.

card payload editor

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.5",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "This line will visible when the condition meet:",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                    "title": "Any button you want to show"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "$when": "${$root.MatchVariableValue == \"yes\"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

use the following sample on Data editor to see how the section appear and hide depending on your input/value.

```
{"MatchVariableValue":"yes"}
```

or use

```
"$when": "${$root.MatchVariableValue}"
```

if your data is as simple as

```
{"MatchVariableValue":true}
```

Comment: The solution you propose works only for the initial value, but if you want to react to any change of MatchVariableValue, it does not work. 
I'm trying to achieve something similar using out-of-the-box functionality but $when does not react to changes on the data model. For example, if you link the ChoiceSet.value to MatchVariableValue you can change that value but the $when clauses are never re-evaluated.

Comment: Do you mean you try to change the value of MatchVariableValue depending on user action in the card? e.g. depending on what they set on ChoiceSet.value? 
If yes, then maybe you can put the condition under the ChoiceSet action and see if that will works?